# HowTo embed an active form (videoPanel) into another form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, iframe, embed, parent

I've a MainForm, with two buttons.
One button calls a form with a "live stream" of my webcam.
The other displays some pictures and now the same form should also show me a live stream in specific times (i.e. every 10mins for 20 sec).
atm it's not possible for me to access the webcam two times via the same application - there VS throw an error "Device is already in use..".
So I thought there has to be another solution. Now I'm thinking about displaying the active form (with the "live stream") for some seconds in my "picture form".
I just tested and played with a new project, only for this embedding...
But I can't rock it... -.-
Hope you guys understood what I'm trying to do and have some ideas :)
Thx in advance.